# Прокрутка

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, прошу помощи в таком вопросе.
Как сверстать блок для прокручивания внутри цифр? 
Яркий пример тому лайки вконтакте. С помощью картинки с цифрами и изменение ее background-position все получилось.
Но как быть с текстом?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css:

```
<style>
.cntr{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  font-size:18px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  }
</style>
```

js:

```
function plus1(cntr)
{
  var cntr=$(cntr),div;
  var i=parseInt(cntr.html());//текущее значение
  if(isNaN(i))return;//анимация не закончилась
  cntr.append(div=$('<div >'+(i+1)+'</div>'));//добавляем следующее число
  cntr.animate({scrollTop: div.offset().top}, //прокручиваем до него
               {
                 duration:600,
                 complete:function(){cntr.html(i+1)}//убираем лишнее после завершения
               });
}
```

body:

```
<div class=cntr onclick='plus1(this)'>1</div>
```

Изложил один из способов. Думаю из кода все ясно.

Comment: расшифруйте пожалуйста  
var cntr=$(cntr),div;

Comment: Расшифровываю: бесполезные действия :) В предыдущей версии передавал селектор - упустил из виду.

Comment: все остальное понятно, спасибо)